# A program to create a lottery game that creates 10 sets without any duplicates, efficiently?

Tags: c++

> A lotto game requires 5 numbers from the range 1 to 35 inclusive. Use random numbers to generate 10 sets of 5 numbers for the lotto game. No number can be repeated in each set.
>
> Generate the winning numbers randomly and determine how many bets got 3 numbers or more correct.

This was part of an assignment I was given. I have tried using a for loop within a for loop to check for duplicates in the sets generated. We aren't allowed to use vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i, j, x, num[5], win[5],n1, n2, count=0, check;
    int match=0, goodBet=0;
    srand(time(NULL));


    //generates the winning numbers for the lottery
    cout << "Winning numbers: " << endl;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        win[i] = rand() % 35 + 1;   
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        check = win[i];
        win[i]=0;

            for(int ld =0;ld<5;ld++){
                if(check == win[ld]){   
                    win[ld]=rand()% 35+1;   
                }
            }
            win[i]=check;
    }

    //prints the lottery numbers
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout << win[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    //generates 10 sets of "bets" to compare to the winning numbers of the 
      lottery to find a winner
    cout << "Bets: " << endl;
    for (x=0; x<10; x++){

        for (i=0; i<5; i++){
            n1 = rand() % 35 + 1;//generates random number
            num[i]=n1;
        }
        /*
        Checks num array for duplicates.Assigns the check variable with 
        the value at num[i]
        afterwards assigns num[i] with 0 to check for duplicates in the 
        array
        */
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            check = num[i];
            num[i]=0;
                for(int ld =0;ld<5;ld++){
                    if(check == num[ld]){
                    count++;
                    num[ld]=rand()% 35+1;   
                    }
                }
                num[i]=check;
        }

        for (i=0; i<5; i++){
            cout << num[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;

        for (i=0; i<5; i++){

            for (j=0; j<5; j++){
                if (num[i] == win[j]){
                    match++;
                }
            }
            if (match >= 3){
                goodBet++;
            }
        }
        match=0;
    }
    cout << endl << goodBet << " bet/s got 3 or more numbers correct" << 
    endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Winning numbers:

10 34 4 25 2

Bets:

20 18 21 25 14

8 9 14 11 6

13 4 24 8 2

35 6 29 28 32

35 15 7 33 22

9 13 27 32 28

17 2 3 23 13

13 28 19 33 6

29 12 28 34 9

35 3 2 13 17

0 bet/s got 3 or more numbers correct

Comment: In addition to expected output and actual output, it would be nice to have a complete program that produces that output. See: [mcve].

Comment: "We aren't allowed to use vectors." Why every C++ assignment has this kind of stupid limitations?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Next time I will put the complete program to get better assistance with it.

Comment: @DimChtz They want to test our knowledge and understanding of arrays before they tell us to vectors.

Comment: Time to read about the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). A.k.a: the Knuth shuffle.

Comment: @NicholasSmith Off-topic, but you should understand vectors thoroughly before studying arrays.

Comment: vectors before arrays ? they told us arrays before vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt to just create an array holding 1..35 inclusive, and then randomly generate indexes into that array, removing the selected element from the array on each iteration.  No need to check for duplicates if they don't exist in the first place.

```
int nums[5];

int numsToChooseFrom[35];
int numsAvailable;
int chosenIndex;

srand(time(0));

for(int set = 0; set < 10; ++set){

    for(int i = 0; i < 35; ++i){
        numsToChooseFrom[i] = i + 1;
    }
    numsAvailable = 35;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        chosenIndex = rand() % numsAvailable;
        nums[i] = numsToChooseFrom[chosenIndex];

        for (int j = chosenIndex+1; j < numsAvailable; ++j) {
            numsToChooseFrom[j-1] = numsToChooseFrom[j];
        }
        --numsAvailable;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/z0sbnl)

Comment: This has the advantage of being deterministic. Discarding selections is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to first generate five random numbers and then check for duplicates. It's much simpler to check for duplicates as you go.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    check = num[i];//assigns check the value in the array at position i
    num[i]=0;//changes it to 0 so it doesn't count this as a duplicate
        for(int ld=0;ld<5;ld++){
            if(check == num[ld]{
                num[ld]=rand()%35+1; // *** Wrong thing
            }
        }
    num[i]=check;
}
```

Use a much simpler algorithm:

1. Pick a random number. Do not store it in the list yet.
2. Set a new integer variable to zero.
3. Iterate over the list of already-chosen numbers, if any match the number we chose in step 1, set the integer from step 2 to the value 1.
4. If the value of the integer is 1, go to step 1.
5. Add the random number to the list.
6. If the list has five numbers, stop. Otherwise, go to step 1.

You could make your original code work, you just need to change what you do if you find a match. If you find a match you need to pick a new random number and start the compare over. So instead of `num[ld]=rand()%35+1;` you'd need something like `check=rand()%35+1; ld=0;`

You also want to get rid of the `num[i]=0;` there. The whole array needs to be set to zero already. Or, alternatively, change `ld<5` to `ld<i`.

Comment: Another option for 2-4 is to declare a `int used[36] = {0};` array within the outer loop and as you generate the random, `do { random = rand % 35 + 1; } while (used[random]); used[random] = 1;`

Comment: Yeah, something like `do { random = rand() % 35 + 1; } while (used[random] != 0); used[random] = 1;` works too.

Comment: Exactly -- I was editing/typing when you posted, scary the result `:)`

Comment: Thank you for the assistance @DavidSchwartz. I have an idea on how to tackle the issue thanks to your algorithm. I won't be able to fix it right away as I am occupied, do i close this question or leave it open until i fix my problem?

Comment: And also thank you @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Ok I made my edit. Unsure if the length is appropriate. This is the code I made changes to and it doesn't output duplicates but I didn't do it the way both of you described. I'm sorry.

Comment: Your edited code is broken. What happens if on the very last iteration of the loop, `num[ld]=rand()% 35+1;` just puts back the value that's already there?

Comment: Sorry if i have to keep changing stuff on the question itself it is my first time using here.

Comment: ok so with your algorithm i will have a separate array, lets called checked[35], initialize each position in the array to zero.

Comment: If there are any more comments will check back later, my house is being flooded right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is minor bug in the way you are checking for the duplicates. Consider the following example:

```
// Initially your list may look like this after having generated five random numbers
//   and you follow the above code to replace duplicates by new random numbers
22 14 22 32 11 

// Iteration 0
22 14 11 32 11 // 2nd index is changed

// Iteration 1
22 14 11 32 11 // No change as 14 is unique in the list

// Iteration 2
22 14 11 32 22 // 4th index is changed

// Iteration 3
22 14 11 32 22 // No change as 32 is unique in the list

// Iteration 4
14 14 11 32 22 // Index 0 is changed
```

Notice that we still have duplicates in the list. So, solution to this problem is to check for all numbers present in the list while generating new random number.

And one more thing, checking with

`if(check == num[ld])
     num[ld]=rand()%35+1;`
does not guarantee that `num[ld]` is not again same as `check`. Instead `while` can be used.